# Flavor changing weak neutral current and $Z^0$ boson

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model, weak-interaction

In Peskin QFT p.725, it says:

> The $K^0$ meson could decay by $Z^0$ exchange if this boson coupled to a flavor changing weak neutral current.

[image]

However, $Z^0$ boson does not couple  to a flavor changing weak neutral current. Just look at the $Z^0$ current at Peskin QFT (20.80):
[image]

The $Z^0$ boson preserves the weak flavor.

> **Question:** So what is the point and the big deal behind Peskin QFT p.725 paragraph re-emphasizing the $Z^0$ boson (which does not have a violating CP-violating current )?

(The 1-loop diagrams of $W$ bosons couple  to a flavor changing weak neutral current - but it is suppressed by GIM mechanism. If you want to discuss and explore this, please feel free, but be as comprehensive as possible -- do not assume we know GIM mechanism...)

Answer (score 1):

We know by now that the Standard Model (SM) is a pretty good description of nature, so the effects of Beyond the Standard Model (BSM) physics are going to be small, at least in the regimes that we are able to probe experimentally. For that reason, it is very difficult to see the effects of BSM physics on a process where the SM prediction is large: the fractional change will be very small. Phenomenologists therefore like to pay a lot of attention to things that the SM predicts are *zero* (maybe due to an exact symmetry) or *very small* (loop/CKM/Yukawa/etc. suppressed). Then the effect of BSM physics could be fractionally large, and thus easier to discover.

My reading of Peskin's intentions here is to point out that FCNCs are such a phenomenon which is very small in the SM, and thus represents an idea experimental target for probing the SM and searching for new physics.